# jquery layout not working while loading through ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview

I have created a layout using JQuery layout. It is working fine if I use it in normal index file. But when I try to load through ui-view directory, it's not loading. Please help.

my index.html`

```
<html ng-app="sample">

<head>
<title>sample</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.all.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.layout.js"></script>
<script src="angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mylayout;
$(document).ready(function(){
myLayout = $('#container').layout({west_size:400,
west_minSize:100
});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ui-view></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="home.js">
</html>
```

`

```
my app.js as bellow;
var SP ={};
SP.CONTROLLERS = angular.module('spControllers',[]);
sp.Dependencies =['spControllers',ui.router,'ngAnimate'
        ];

spModule = angular.module('spModule',SP.dependencies)
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider',
function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$httpProvider){

$stateProider.
    state('home',{
        url:'',
        templateurl:'home.html'
    })
}]);
```

my home.html is as below;

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="smpCTRL">
<div class="pane ui-layout-west">WEST</div>
<div class="pane ui-layout-center">CENTER</div>
</div>
```

my home.js is as below;

```
   SP>CONTROLLERS.controller("smpCTRL", ['$scope',function($scope){
console.log("sucess");
}]);
```

css as below;

```
#container {
        background: #999;
        height:     100%;
        margin:     0 auto;
        width:      100%;
        max-width:  900px;
        min-width:  700px;
        _width:     700px; /* min-width for IE6 */
    }
    .pane {
        display:    none; /* will appear when layout inits */
    }


/*
 * Default Layout Theme
 *
 * Created for jquery.layout 
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 
 *   Fabrizio Balliano (http://www.fabrizioballiano.net)
 *   Kevin Dalman (http://allpro.net)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the GPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
 * and MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Last Updated: 2010-02-10
 * NOTE: For best code readability, view this with a fixed-space font and tabs equal to 4-chars
 */

/*
 *  DEFAULT FONT
 *  Just to make demo-pages look better - not actually relevant to Layout!
 */
body {
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:   100%;
    *font-size:  80%;
}

/*
 *  PANES & CONTENT-DIVs
 */
.ui-layout-pane { /* all 'panes' */
    background: #FFF; 
    border:     1px solid #BBB;
    padding:    10px; 
    overflow:   auto;
    /* DO NOT add scrolling (or padding) to 'panes' that have a content-div,
       otherwise you may get double-scrollbars - on the pane AND on the content-div
       - use ui-layout-wrapper class if pane has a content-div
       - use ui-layout-container if pane has an inner-layout
    */
    }
    /* (scrolling) content-div inside pane allows for fixed header(s) and/or footer(s) */
    .ui-layout-content {
        padding:    10px;
        position:   relative; /* contain floated or positioned elements */
        overflow:   auto; /* add scrolling to content-div */
    }

/*
 *  UTILITY CLASSES
 *  Must come AFTER pane-class above so will override
 *  These classes are NOT auto-generated and are NOT used by Layout
 */
.layout-child-container,
.layout-content-container {
    padding:    0;
    overflow:   hidden;
}
.layout-child-container {
    border:     0; /* remove border because inner-layout-panes probably have borders */
}
.layout-scroll {
    overflow:   auto;
}
.layout-hide {
    display:    none;
}

/*
 *  RESIZER-BARS
 */
.ui-layout-resizer  { /* all 'resizer-bars' */
    background:     #DDD;
    border:         1px solid #BBB;
    border-width:   0;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-drag {       /* REAL resizer while resize in progress */
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-hover    {   /* affects both open and closed states */
    }
    /* NOTE: It looks best when 'hover' and 'dragging' are set to the same color,
        otherwise color shifts while dragging when bar can't keep up with mouse */
    .ui-layout-resizer-open-hover , /* hover-color to 'resize' */
    .ui-layout-resizer-dragging {   /* resizer beging 'dragging' */
        background: #C4E1A4;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-dragging {   /* CLONED resizer being dragged */
        border:      1px solid #BBB;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-north-dragging,
    .ui-layout-resizer-south-dragging {
        border-width:   1px 0;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-west-dragging,
    .ui-layout-resizer-east-dragging {
        border-width:   0 1px;
    }
    /* NOTE: Add a 'dragging-limit' color to provide visual feedback when resizer hits min/max size limits */
    .ui-layout-resizer-dragging-limit { /* CLONED resizer at min or max size-limit */
        background: #E1A4A4; /* red */
    }

    .ui-layout-resizer-closed-hover { /* hover-color to 'slide open' */
        background: #EBD5AA;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-sliding {    /* resizer when pane is 'slid open' */
        opacity: .10; /* show only a slight shadow */
        filter:  alpha(opacity=10);
        }
        .ui-layout-resizer-sliding-hover {  /* sliding resizer - hover */
            opacity: 1.00; /* on-hover, show the resizer-bar normally */
            filter:  alpha(opacity=100);
        }
        /* sliding resizer - add 'outside-border' to resizer on-hover 
         * this sample illustrates how to target specific panes and states */
        .ui-layout-resizer-north-sliding-hover  { border-bottom-width:  1px; }
        .ui-layout-resizer-south-sliding-hover  { border-top-width:     1px; }
        .ui-layout-resizer-west-sliding-hover   { border-right-width:   1px; }
        .ui-layout-resizer-east-sliding-hover   { border-left-width:    1px; }

/*
 *  TOGGLER-BUTTONS
 */
.ui-layout-toggler {
    border: 1px solid #BBB; /* match pane-border */
    background-color: #BBB;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer-hover .ui-layout-toggler {
        opacity: .60;
        filter:  alpha(opacity=60);
    }
    .ui-layout-toggler-hover , /* need when NOT resizable */
    .ui-layout-resizer-hover .ui-layout-toggler-hover { /* need specificity when IS resizable */
        background-color: #FC6;
        opacity: 1.00;
        filter:  alpha(opacity=100);
    }
    .ui-layout-toggler-north ,
    .ui-layout-toggler-south {
        border-width: 0 1px; /* left/right borders */
    }
    .ui-layout-toggler-west ,
    .ui-layout-toggler-east {
        border-width: 1px 0; /* top/bottom borders */
    }
    /* hide the toggler-button when the pane is 'slid open' */
    .ui-layout-resizer-sliding  .ui-layout-toggler {
        display: none;
    }
    /*
     *  style the text we put INSIDE the togglers
     */
    .ui-layout-toggler .content {
        color:          #666;
        font-size:      12px;
        font-weight:    bold;
        width:          100%;
        padding-bottom: 0.35ex; /* to 'vertically center' text inside text-span */
    }

/*
 *  PANE-MASKS
 *  these styles are hard-coded on mask elems, but are also 
 *  included here as !important to ensure will overrides any generic styles
 */
.ui-layout-mask {
    border:     none !important;
    padding:    0 !important;
    margin:     0 !important;
    overflow:   hidden !important;
    position:   absolute !important;
    opacity:    0 !important;
    filter:     Alpha(Opacity="0") !important;
}
.ui-layout-mask-inside-pane { /* masks always inside pane EXCEPT when pane is an iframe */
    top:        0 !important;
    left:       0 !important;
    width:      100% !important;
    height:     100% !important;
}
div.ui-layout-mask {}       /* standard mask for iframes */
iframe.ui-layout-mask {}    /* extra mask for objects/applets */

/*
 *  Default printing styles
 */
@media print {
    /*
     *  Unless you want to print the layout as it appears onscreen,
     *  these html/body styles are needed to allow the content to 'flow'
     */
    html {
        height:     auto !important;
        overflow:   visible !important;
    }
    body.ui-layout-container {
        position:   static !important;
        top:        auto !important;
        bottom:     auto !important;
        left:       auto !important;
        right:      auto !important;
        /* only IE6 has container width & height set by Layout */
        _width:     auto !important;
        _height:    auto !important;
    }
    .ui-layout-resizer, .ui-layout-toggler {
        display:    none !important;
    }
    /*
     *  Default pane print styles disables positioning, borders and backgrounds.
     *  You can modify these styles however it suit your needs.
     */
    .ui-layout-pane {
        border:     none !important;
        background:  transparent !important;
        position:   relative !important;
        top:        auto !important;
        bottom:     auto !important;
        left:       auto !important;
        right:      auto !important;
        width:      auto !important;
        height:     auto !important;
        overflow:   visible !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is woring fine without ui-router concept for angular application. able to load an angulajs grid without ui-router

Answer (score 1):

This is how I get it solved:

1. In your app.js, create is on controller,
2. add the controller name to your index body.
3. the convert the template js to a method.
4. then create a scope method in your app.js controller.
5. In the scope method, call the template js method.
6. Inside the ui-view html template or your dashboard. Use ng-init to call the scope method of your app.js controller using `<div ng-init='$parent.appTemplate()'></div>`.

Here is the working example (index.html):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="zeusWeb" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Screening Manager</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="education, institution, management, portal,screening,application">
  <meta name="description" content="education, institution, management, portal,screening,application">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <meta name="author" content="K-Devs System Solutions">
  <meta name="owner" content="Kazeem Olanipekun">
  <meta name="verified by" content="K-Devs System Solutions">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
  <meta name="google" content="translate">
  <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 month">
  <!-- build:css css/main.css-->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/iCheck/skins/flat/blue.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/switchery/dist/switchery.css" />
  <!--endbower-->
  <!--custom:css-->
  <link href="template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <!-- endcustom  css-->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/screening.ico" type='image/x-icon'/>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/screening.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="zeusWebCtrl" class="nav-md footer_fixed">
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <data ui-view ng-cloak></data>

  <!-- build:js js/vendors.js-->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/iCheck/icheck.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/transitionize/dist/transitionize.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/switchery/dist/switchery.js"></script>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->


  <!-- build:js js/main.js-->
  <!-- code inclusion-->
  <script src="template.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/dashboard/dashboard.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <!--end inclusion -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the app.js:

```js
    'use strict';
    // Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
    var zeusWeb=angular.module('zeusWeb', ['ui.router', 'angular-loading-bar','dashboard']);
    zeusWeb.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','cfpLoadingBarProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,cfpLoadingBarProvider) {

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
      /**
       *   State for the very first page of the app. This is the home page .
       */
      $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
      });
    /*
      $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
            url:'/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'dashboardCtrl',
            controllerAs:'vm'
      });*/

    /*
      $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
        views:{
          'body':{
            url:'/embed',
            templateUrl: 'view1/embed.html',
            controller: 'embed',
            controllerAs:'vm'
          }
        }
      });*/

    }]);
    zeusWeb.controller('zeusWebCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
      $scope.test = "Testing";
      $scope.appTemplate=function () {
      template();
      };

    }]);
```

Here is the embed ui-view dashboard.html:

```html
    <div  class="container body">
        <div class="main_container">
            <!--sidebar-->
            <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/sidebar-nav.html'" data-ng-controller="sideBarCtrl as vm"></section>
            <!--sidebar-->

            <!-- top navigation -->
            <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/header.html'"></section>
            <!-- /top navigation -->

            <!-- page content -->
            <div class="right_col" role="main" ui-view="body">
                hey
              <!--  <script>template();</script>-->
            </div>
            <!-- /page content -->
            <!--footer-->
            <section  data-ng-include="'views/dashboard/footer.html'"></section>
            <!--footer-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-init="$parent.appTemplate()"></div>
```

Please note that if you are having an asynchronous inject sidebars html based on roles. make sure you have a default sidebar html that will put this `<div data-ng-init="$parent.appTemplate()"></div>` instead of the dashboard and also make sure that the default sidebar will be loaded last after all other sidebars has loaded successfully.

In my case, here is a sample example of the sidebars (school admin html sidebar):

```html
<div  class="menu_section">
    <h3>Live On</h3>
    <ul class="nav side-menu">
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="page_403.html">403 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Menu <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a>
                <li><a>Level One<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="level2.html">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#level1_2">Level One</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, let assume that is the last sidebar of the user, then you then call the default sidebar to call the function (default sidebar html):

```html
    <div data-ng-init="$parent.appTemplate()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try your code after angular DOM is ready

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    myLayout = $('#container').layout({west_size:400,
      west_minSize:100
    });
});
```

Comment: He is already doing this. $(document).ready and angular.element(document) are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.layout` is called before the element #container exists.

The correct solution for this would be to create a directive for the 'layout' function and apply that directive to the element you want to set the layout to.

Answer (score 0):

Include your script inside your home.html partial template, that should work, had a similar issue, my guess is that that particular dom element does not exist when your function is initially executed.

**home.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mylayout;
$(document).ready(function(){
myLayout = $('#container').layout({west_size:400,
west_minSize:100
});
})
</script>

<div id="container" ng-controller="smpCTRL">
<div class="pane ui-layout-west">WEST</div>
<div class="pane ui-layout-center">CENTER</div>
</div>
```