# AngularJS ui-view not getting javascript file of it's parent page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Initially when the page load all ui-view loaded and works fine But when i change the state ui-view not getting javascript file that loaded earlier in it's parent page.Although ui view gets the css file but not js file.

In the index.html all three ui-view viewA,viewB,viewC and navbar.html is template of ui-viewA.
[image]

Here is the state configuration. When i go to studentDashboard the navbar.html loaded but it's js function that define in vendor/all.js doesn't working. 
[image]

Here is the navbar html and controller
[image]

Comment: are you looking fro nested router?

Comment: correct your body tag it has extra >

Comment: share a screenshot of your navbar and your navbarController code..

Comment: Make sure navbarCtrl in navbarController has the correct spelling

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan i have attached the screenshot.

Comment: I doubt your approch is right

Comment: @user2181397 sorry i don't get you.

Comment: so what do you mean not getting javascript file? $scope.btnStatus in navbarCtrl is not working? do you see any errors in console?

Comment: @MuthukannanKanniappan no not the $scope.btnStatus. those i define in  /public/assets/css/vendor/all.css" and /public/assets/css/app/app.css" .
they work fine when the page load after i change the state they are not working.

Comment: i get it solved, You can check the explanation through this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832243/jquery-layout-not-working-while-loading-through-ui-view/41087345#41087345

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it by converting the js file into a method and render the function inside the ui-view html containing the child page. this approach will work but the downside is when working with directive to inject the sidebar content dynamically. it will require you to duplicate  a separate css of same type for each roles and likewise the js too.